# how to extract all values from a data frame by month for years

Tags: r, zoo

I have data in a zoo data structure. I want to pull all August daily vaules over 10 years and compute monthly statistics for a period of record. Any thoughts on easy way to do this?

Comment: Please show us what you have so far: your data, your code and the exact moment you are stuck at. See the [following guideline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Please read this for how to create a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, I actually found a package that calculated the statistic I was manually trying to calculate, monthly mean and mean monthly.

Answer (score 0):

an example will be great of the specific date format, however, try `format()`

for example:

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2009-08-03 12:01:59.23")
format(x,"%b")
```

For simplicity, just create a new column with the format() then subset it with the month your looking for.